# Dual screen support on Android tablet

Tags: android, tablet

I am looking for a solution using hardware and/or software to display content which is split into two LCD screens side-by-side (like in desktop systems with two monitors) for Android tablet.

There will be two touch screens of 1080 x 800px resolution each and will take input from both touch and display, becoming a extension of the first screen.

Either 32 or 64 bit ARM processor is okay as long as the problem is solved.

I found Rockchip RK3288 supports dual screen but not sure if it makes a copy of the first screen or extends the display.

Any pointers to using special off-the-shelf circuit or configuration will be of great help too.

Comment: Just to clarify, you are looking for an android tablet, right? Or are you looking for a device that extends the display of an existing tablet?

Comment: Any reason you a specific to an Android Tablet?  Would a Windows tablet be acceptable?

Comment: Actually OS doesn't matter as long as the hardware supports it. I know there are a few Android phones that have similar capabilities but I want to design similar for my own on a tablet. Android is preferable as it is open source and can be tweaked. I will be making this prototype from scratch.